# Problems running kapacitor localinstall inside dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, kapacitor

I am trying to install Kapacitor over Cent-OS base, but, I am facing problems with executing the localinstall command (or so I think) when I build the dockerfile.

My dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM centos-base:7   

ENV CONFIG_HOME /usr/local/bin

RUN curl -O https://dl.influxdata.com/kapacitor/releases/kapacitor-0.13.1.x86_64.rpm

RUN yum localinstall kapacitor-0.13.1.x86_64.rpm 

COPY kapacitor.conf $CONFIG_HOME
ENTRYPOINT["/bin/bash"]
```

When I build it, I get the following response:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.072 kB
Step 1 : FROM centos-base:7
 ---> 9ab68a0dd16a
Step 2 : ENV CONFIG_HOME /usr/local/bin
 ---> Running in ef5b7206e55d
 ---> 7c1b42d279db
Removing intermediate container ef5b7206e55d
Step 3 : RUN curl -O https://dl.influxdata.com/kapacitor/releases/kapacitor-0.13.1.x86_64.rpm
 ---> Running in 681bb29474f9
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 10.8M  100 10.8M    0     0   123k      0  0:01:29  0:01:29 --:--:--  224k
 ---> 99b4e77c89f2
Removing intermediate container 681bb29474f9
Step 4 : RUN yum localinstall kapacitor-0.13.1.x86_64.rpm
 ---> Running in d67ad03f4830
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Repodata is over 2 weeks old. Install yum-cron? Or run: yum makecache fast
Examining kapacitor-0.13.1.x86_64.rpm: kapacitor-0.13.1-1.x86_64
Marking kapacitor-0.13.1.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package kapacitor.x86_64 0:0.13.1-1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package        Arch        Version         Repository                     Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 kapacitor      x86_64      0.13.1-1        /kapacitor-0.13.1.x86_64       41 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total size: 41 M
Installed size: 41 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: Exiting on user command
Your transaction was saved, rerun it with:
 yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx.2016-08-31.04-00.gvfpqf.yumtx
The command '/bin/sh -c yum localinstall kapacitor-0.13.1.x86_64.rpm' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Where am I going wrong? Can't I execute a localinstall inside Dockerfile? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
RUN yum localinstall kapacitor-0.13.1.x86_64.rpm
```

with

```
RUN yum -y localinstall kapacitor-0.13.1.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: thanks. That worked. But, now, there seems to be some problem with last instruction as it gives the error 'Unknown instruction: ENTRYPOINT["/BIN/BASH"]`. Am I doing something wrong there?

Comment: @RohanSingh You have to put a space between `ENTRYPOINT` and `['/bin/bash']`